# Why Parsec's sepBy stops and does not parse all elements?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am trying to parse some comma separated string which may or may not contain a string with image dimensions. For example `"hello world, 300x300, good bye world"`.

I've written the following little program:

```
import Text.Parsec
import qualified Text.Parsec.Text as PS

parseTestString :: Text -> [Maybe (Int, Int)]
parseTestString s = case parse dimensStringParser "" s of
                      Left _ -> [Nothing]
                      Right dimens -> dimens

dimensStringParser :: PS.Parser [Maybe (Int, Int)]
dimensStringParser = (optionMaybe dimensParser) `sepBy` (char ',')

dimensParser :: PS.Parser (Int, Int)
dimensParser = do
  w <- many1 digit
  char 'x'
  h <- many1 digit
  return (read w, read h)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ parseTestString "300x300,40x40,5x5"
  print $ parseTestString "300x300,hello,5x5,6x6"
```

According to `optionMaybe` documentation, it returns `Nothing` if it can't parse, so I would expect to get this output:

```
[Just (300,300),Just (40,40),Just (5,5)]
[Just (300,300),Nothing, Just (5,5), Just (6,6)]
```

but instead I get:

```
[Just (300,300),Just (40,40),Just (5,5)]
[Just (300,300),Nothing]
```

I.e. parsing stops after first failure. So I have two questions:

1. Why does it behave this way?
2. How do I write a correct parser for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to answer this question, it's handy to take a piece of paper, write down the input, and act as a dumb parser.

We start with "300x300,hello,5x5,6x6", our current parser is `optionMaybe ...`. Does our `dimensParser` correctly parse the dimension? Let's check:

```
  w <- many1 digit   -- yes, "300"
  char 'x'           -- yes, "x"
  h <- many1 digit   -- yes, "300"
  return (read w, read h) -- never fails
```

We've successfully parsed the first dimension. The next token is `,`, so `sepBy` successfully parses that as well. Next, we try to parse "hello" and fail:

```
 w <- many1 digit -- no. 'h' is not a digit. Stop
```

Next, `sepBy` tries to parse `,`, but that's not possible, since the next token is a `'h'`, not a `,`. Therefore, `sepBy` stops.

We haven't parsed *all* the input, but that's not actually necessary. You would get a proper error message if you've used

```
parse (dimensStringParser <* eof)
```

Either way, if you want to discard anything in the list that's not a dimension, you can use

```
dimensStringParser1 :: Parser (Maybe (Int, Int))
dimensStringParser1 = (Just <$> dimensParser) <|> (skipMany (noneOf ",") >> Nothing)

dimensStringParser = dimensStringParser1  `sepBy` char ','
```

Comment: Thank you! Another great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that `optionMaybe dimensParser`, when fed with input `"hello,..."`, tries `dimensParser`. That fails, so `optionMaybe` returns success with `Nothing`, and consumes no portion of the input.

The last part is the crucial one: after `Nothing` is returned, the input string to be parsed is still `"hello,..."`.

At that point `sepBy` tries to parse `char ','`, which fails. So, it deduces that the list is over, and terminates the output list, without consuming any more input.

If you want to skip other entities, you need a "consuming" parser that returns `Nothing` instead of `optionMaybe`. That parser, however, need to know how much to consume: in your case, until the comma.

Perhaps you need some like (untested)

```
(   try (Just <$> dimensParser) 
<|> (noneOf "," >> return Nothing))
    `sepBy` char ','
```

Comment: Oh, seems like that's what's happening indeed. Now I need to think a bit on how to fix this situation :)

Comment: Thanks, will try your suggestion a bit later. I have tried something like `(optionMaybe dimensParser) <|> skipMany anyChar`, but it led to the same results. I guess that's because it still consumed comma and fooled sepBy

Comment: @dimsuz `optionMaybe` always succeeds, so the `skipMany` is never used.