# Haskell - Parsec with state

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I have a file in which the state of a game is saved in `String` format. This string consists of a list of moves, seperated by `,`. From this list of moves I have to reconstruct the game state. Thus, conceptually, for each move I parse I want to modify the gamestate appropriatly and pass this gamestate to the parsing of the next move. Conceptually, this could be equivalent with having an empty list at the start and for each move consing the parsed move to that list. At the end you should have a list with all parsed moves.

I made the code example below as a simplified version to parse alfabetic letters and push these on the list. The core concept I want to learn is how to have an initial state, pass this on for each parsing cycle and return the final state using parsec. `someState` is the empty list initially.

```
parseExample :: State -> Parser [Char]
parseExample someState = do spaces 
                            c <- char 
                            c : someState
                            return someState
```

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to incorporate a "state" into a parser is not to do it at all.  Let's say we have a tic-tac-toe board:

```
data Piece = X | O | N deriving (Show)
type Board = [[Piece]]
```

To parse a list of moves:

```
X11,O00,X01
```

into a board `[[O,X,N],[N,X,N],[N,N,N]]` representing the game state:

```
 O | X |
---+---+---
   | X |
---+---+---
   |   |
```

we can separate the parser, which just generates a list of moves:

```
data Move = Move Piece Int Int
moves :: Parser [Move]
moves = sepBy move (char ',')
  where move = Move <$> piece <*> num <*> num
        piece = X <$ char 'X' <|> O <$ char 'O'
        num = read . (:[]) <$> digit
```

from the functions that regenerate the game state:

```
board0 :: Board
board0 = [[N,N,N],[N,N,N],[N,N,N]]

game :: [Move] -> Board
game = foldl' turn board0

turn :: Board -> Move -> Board
turn brd (Move p r c) = brd & ix r . ix c .~ p
```

and then connect them together in a `loadGame` function:

```
loadGame :: String -> Board
loadGame str =
  case parse moves "" str of
    Left err -> error $ "parse error: " ++ show err
    Right mvs -> game mvs
```

This should be your go-to solution for this kind of problem: parse first into a simple stateless intermediate form, and then process this intermediate form in a "stateful" computation.

If you *really* want to build up the state during the parse, there are several ways to do it.  In this particular case, given the definition of `turn` above, we can parse directly into a `Board` by incorporating the fold from the `game` function into the parser:

```
moves1 :: Parser Board
moves1 = foldl' turn board0 <$> sepBy move (char ',')
  where move = Move <$> piece <*> num <*> num
        piece = X <$ char 'X' <|> O <$ char 'O'
        num = read . (:[]) <$> digit
```

but this won't generalize too well if you have multiple parsers that need to operate on a single underlying state.

To actually thread a state through a set of parsers, you can use the "user state" feature of Parsec.  Define a parser with a `Board` user state:

```
type Parser' = Parsec String Board
```

and then a parser for a single move that modifies the user state:

```
move' :: Parser' ()
move' = do
  m <- Move <$> piece <*> num <*> num
  modifyState (flip turn m)
  where piece = X <$ char 'X' <|> O <$ char 'O'
        num = read . (:[]) <$> digit
```

Note that `move'`'s return type is `()` because its action is implemented as a side-effect on the user state.

Now, the act of simply parsing a list of moves:

```
moves' :: Parser' ()
moves' = sepBy move' (char ',')
```

will generate the final game state:

```
loadGame' :: String -> Board
loadGame' str =
  case runParser (moves' >> getState) [[N,N,N],[N,N,N],[N,N,N]] "" str of
    Left err -> error $ "parse error: " ++ show err
    Right brd -> brd
```

Here, `loadGame'` runs the parser on the user state with `moves'` and then uses a `getState` call to fetch the final board.

A nearly equivalent solution, since `ParsecT` is a monad transformer, is to create a `ParsecT ... (State Board)` monad transformer stack with a standard `State` layer.  For example:

```
type Parser'' = ParsecT String () (Control.Monad.State.State Board)

move'' :: Parser'' ()
move'' = do
  m <- Move <$> piece <*> num <*> num
  modify (flip turn m)
  where piece = X <$ char 'X' <|> O <$ char 'O'
        num = read . (:[]) <$> digit

moves'' :: Parser'' ()
moves'' = void $ sepBy move'' (char ',')

loadGame'' :: String -> Board
loadGame'' str =
  case runState (runParserT moves'' () "" str) board0 of
    (Left err, _)   -> error $ "parse error: " ++ show err
    (Right (), brd) -> brd
```

However, both these approaches of building up a state while parsing are weird and non-standard.  A parser written in this form will be harder to understand and modify than the standard approach.  Also, the intended usage for a user state is to maintain state that's necessary for the parser to decide how to perform the actual parse.  For example, if you were parsing a language with dynamic operator precedence, you might want to maintain the current set of operator precedences as states, so when you parse an `infixr 8 **` line, you can modify the state to correctly parse subsequent expressions.  Using the user state to actually build up the *result* of the parse is not the intended usage.

Anyway, here's the code I used:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Foldable
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.String

data Piece = X | O | N deriving (Show)
type Board = [[Piece]]

data Move = Move Piece Int Int

-- *Standard parsing approach

moves :: Parser [Move]
moves = sepBy move (char ',')
  where move = Move <$> piece <*> num <*> num
        piece = X <$ char 'X' <|> O <$ char 'O'
        num = read . (:[]) <$> digit

board0 :: Board
board0 = [[N,N,N],[N,N,N],[N,N,N]]

game :: [Move] -> Board
game = foldl' turn board0

turn :: Board -> Move -> Board
turn brd (Move p r c) = brd & ix r . ix c .~ p

loadGame :: String -> Board
loadGame str =
  case parse moves "" str of
    Left err -> error $ "parse error: " ++ show err
    Right mvs -> game mvs

-- *Incoporate fold into parser

moves1 :: Parser Board
moves1 = foldl' turn board0 <$> sepBy move (char ',')
  where move = Move <$> piece <*> num <*> num
        piece = X <$ char 'X' <|> O <$ char 'O'
        num = read . (:[]) <$> digit

-- *Non-standard effectful parser

type Parser' = Parsec String Board

move' :: Parser' ()
move' = do
  m <- Move <$> piece <*> num <*> num
  modifyState (flip turn m)
  where piece = X <$ char 'X' <|> O <$ char 'O'
        num = read . (:[]) <$> digit

moves' :: Parser' ()
moves' = void $ sepBy move' (char ',')

loadGame' :: String -> Board
loadGame' str =
  case runParser (moves' >> getState) board0 "" str of
    Left err -> error $ "parse error: " ++ show err
    Right brd -> brd

-- *Monad transformer stack

type Parser'' = ParsecT String () (Control.Monad.State.State Board)

move'' :: Parser'' ()
move'' = do
  m <- Move <$> piece <*> num <*> num
  modify (flip turn m)
  where piece = X <$ char 'X' <|> O <$ char 'O'
        num = read . (:[]) <$> digit

moves'' :: Parser'' ()
moves'' = void $ sepBy move'' (char ',')

loadGame'' :: String -> Board
loadGame'' str =
  case runState (runParserT moves'' () "" str) board0 of
    (Left err, _)   -> error $ "parse error: " ++ show err
    (Right (), brd) -> brd

-- *Tests

main = do
  print $ loadGame   "X11,O00,X01"
  print $ loadGame'  "X11,O00,X01"
  print $ loadGame'' "X11,O00,X01"
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use foldl (if I am understanding your question correctly). So you'll end up with a function like:

```
module Main where

import Data.Text
import Data.String

main :: IO ()
main =
  putStrLn (show $ parseGameState "a, b, c")

data State = State deriving (Show)

parseGameState :: String -> [State]
parseGameState stateString = parsedState where
  parsedState = Prelude.foldl mkNewStateFromPreviousAndMove [] moves where
    moves = splitOn (fromString ",") (fromString stateString)
    mkNewStateFromPreviousAndMove oldStates move = oldStates ++ [newState previousState move] where
      previousState = Prelude.last oldStates
      newState previousState move = State
```

What this is doing is:

Taking the CSV move string as input.

It is then splitting that string into a list of move strings.

Then, we start with an empty list, and fold the move strings into this list by applying mkNewStateFromPreviousAndMove to each element in the moves list and the last element of the list which is built up by the fold.

Note, you will need to add the following deps to your package.yaml file (if using stack):

- text

This dep is used to split strings.

Comment: From my understanding, you're not using parsec in this example right? This would be one of the requirements as my other features are implemented with those parser combinators.

Comment: Hmm no I'm not, but you said: "The core concept I want to learn is how to have an initial state, pass this on for each parsing cycle and return the final state.", I think (and I'm no haskell expert) that `foldl` will be the tool you want for this. You will want to use Parsec on the final line of the function I posted in order to actually parse a given move string (if that's what you plan to use it for?)

Comment: Hey, just did some research, I think you may want `sepBy`. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048903/why-parsecs-sepby-stops-and-does-not-parse-all-elements

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html